# how to draw data from multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server, database, join, sql-server-2014

I have 2 different tables. I need to get a name from the TMK table in table 1 as below, and I need to bring the total number from my 2nd table. I can't write join. can u help me

***TMK Table;***

```
| tmkName | 

| George  |

| Jacob   |
```

***flowNewStatus Table;***

```
|statusId|

| 1 |

| 2 |
```

***if george has number 1 status i want this join***

```
| tmkName |  |statusId|
| George  |    | 1 |
```

Comment: If your tables only have 1 column each, how you are defining the relationship?

Comment: @Chanukya and what happens if the statement `INSERT INTO TMK VALUES ('Dave');` is run? Should George's status become 2? (also, comment's aren't the right place for answers)

Comment: @Larnu for existing data setup i had given not with new insertions

Comment: @Chanukya my point is that assuming the OP's data will never change is a poor assumption.

Comment: @Larnu yeah correct why we need to have unnecessary discussion the person who is asked the question has no response let's close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before getting to possible SQL queries... from the tables you show you'd need an additional table that associates the *person* to *status*, a `join` table. Essentially a **TMK_status** table:

**TMK_status table**

```
| personID | statusID |
|----------|----------|
|    1     |    1     |
|    2     |    3     |
|    3     |    1     |
```

Alternatively, the statusID could be stored as a column of TMK thus,

**TMK table**

```
| personID | tmkName  | statusID |
|----------|----------|----------|
|    1     |  George  |    1     |
|    2     |  Jacob   |    3     |
```

If by "*I can't write join*", you mean you don't know how, check this answer: [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join/38578#38578) - you will need an **inner** join.

If, on on the other hand, you mean you can't use `join` statements, then you could write a `subselect` statement. There could be other solutions but they depend on how you decide to join/relate the 2 tables.

Comment: Please don't answer unclear questions. It makes a mess. Comment asking for edits that clarify. If you don't have the rep then wait.